# Grepping class name if contains main function by bash script

Tags: awk, sed

I am writing script that grep the class name of java file containing multiple class, if it contains main function.
Example: My file contain `text.txt`

```
class Parent 
{
    public void p1()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent method");
    }
}
public class Child extends Parent {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child cobj = new Child();
        cobj.c1();   //method of Child class
        cobj.p1();   //method of Parent class
    }
  public void c1()
    {
        System.out.println("Child method");
    }
}
```

Output will be: `Child`  because it conatins main function. I analyze the pattern and grep two line before the pattern main found in a file.
My script:

```
grep  -B 2 "public static void main" "text.txt" > sample.txt
filen=$(grep -oP '(?<=class )[^ ]*' sample.txt)
echo $filen
```

But my approach gets wrong if code contains like:

```
class Parent
{
    public void p1()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent method");
    }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void c1()
    {
        System.out.println("Child method");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child cobj = new Child();
        cobj.c1();   //method of Child class
        cobj.p1();   //method of Parent class
    }
}
```

Please help me in finding correct approach.

Comment: Not clear, please do mention how you need that output with logic.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Are you asking about my script code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux I would do it like this:

```
grep -e 'public class\|public static void main\>' text.txt  | grep -B1 "public static void main" | grep '\<class\>' | sed "s/^.*class \+//;s/ .*$//"
```

- `grep -e 'public class\|public static void main\>' text.txt`: Grep all lines that either contain "public class" or "public static void main".
- `| grep -B1 "public static void main"`: grep the line containing "public static void main" and one line before.
- `| grep '\<class\>'`: Greps the line containing the word "class".
- `| sed "s/^.*class \+//;s/ .*$//"`: Get rid of everything around the class name.

Note `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries. So `\<class\>` matches the word "class" but not "declassified".

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following once.

```
 awk '/public static void main>/{print val} /public class/{val=$3}' Input_file
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for word boundaries. Personally I'd just get rid of the `\>` so it's portable to all awks since any regexp-based solution will be imprecise anyway. The `.*` in your regexp is doing nothing useful btw, just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl. The below works for both scenarios. Note that grep and awk may give incorrect results when you have more than 2 spaces between public/static/class etc

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' /\bpublic\s+class\s+(\S+).+?public\s*static\s*void\s*main/ms and print "$1\n" ' arya2.txt
Child

$ cat arya2.txt
class Parent
{
    public void p1()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent method");
    }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void c1()
    {
        System.out.println("Child method");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child cobj = new Child();
        cobj.c1();   //method of Child class
        cobj.p1();   //method of Parent class
    }
}
```